# PHP CURL Web Service Call

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I have the following code in order to call a Web Service from php, using curl:

```
<?php
echo "Init<br />";
$url = 'http://server-ip/applications/time2gate.aspx?x=1182&y=365&map=1002&gate=B3&mode=time2gate&session=5fdf288d-01b0-414a-ba2a-58d3f624e453';

$ch = curl_init($url);
echo "1";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$status_code = array();
preg_match('/\d\d\d/', $resp, $status_code);

switch($status_code[0]) {
        case 200:
            echo "Success<br />";
            break;
    case 503:
            die('Your call to Web Service failed and returned an HTTP 503.');
            break;
    case 403:
            die('Your call to Web Service failed and returned an HTTP status of 403.');
            break;
    case 400:
            die('Your call to Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 400.');
            break;
    default:
            die('Your call to Web Services returned an unexpected HTTP status of:' .    $status_code[0]);
}

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

The problem is that I receive HTTP response codes like 163, 815, 329... Why is this happening? What do these codes mean? I checked Apache's error log and I have not seen any errors on my code. Also, I tested a call to the url provided and it works with Mozilla's Poster Add-on.

Any ideas? I am working with php 5, on Ubuntu 12.

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: Are you sure they are HTTP response codes? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes They don't look familiar

Comment: Well I followed the instructions from http://developer.yahoo.com/php/howto-reqRestPhp.html . Is there another way to check the HTTP response code?

Comment: Probably, but without the actual output from the service call the best answer you're going to get is a wild guess.

Comment: How can I print the actual output from the service call then?

Answer (score 1):

When I need to make API calls I use a simple library available on GitHub: https://github.com/rmccue/Requests

I've put an example below which uses this library and it will print out the full response from the API.

```
<?php

require_once('library/Requests.php');

$url = 'http://server-ip/applications/time2gate.aspx?x=1182&y=365&map=1002&gate=B3&mode=time2gate&session=5fdf288d-01b0-414a-ba2a-58d3f624e453';

// Next, make sure Requests can load internal classes
Requests::register_autoloader();

// Now let's make a request!
$request = Requests::get($url, array('Accept' => 'application/json'));

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($request);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I want to stick with pure php-curl web service calls.